# Can't assign char value to pointer in struct

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

**I can't assign the value into the pointer in struct as below**
.

.
.

```
struct Matrix
{
    char *A[10];
    char *Psedo[10];
    int depth;
    int startrow;
    int startcolumn;
    int exitrow;
    int exitcolumn;
};
struct Matrix matrixs ; // create new global struct

void createPsedoEmptyMatrixForBackTracking()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixs.depth; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixs.depth; x++)
        {
            matrixs.Psedo[i][x] = '0';
        }
    }
    printf("DONE");
}

void startMove()
{
    createPsedoEmptyMatrixForBackTracking();
}

int main(){
   startMove();
}
```

.

This is not the full code , but my **matrixs.depth** right now is **5** and as my compiler result the **printf("DONE") never show up** and the **value also not assign into the Psedo** variable i have no idea why

Then i tried

**strcpy(matrixs.Psedo[i][x], '0')**

instead of

**matrixs.Psedo[i][x] = '0';**
.

.

**And this shown up**

warning: passing argument 1 of **'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast** [-Wint-conversion]

and also the **printf("DONE)**; *never show up*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to `Psedo` variable. It is an array of pointers. Where do they point to? They are not pointing to any valid memory location. Accessing it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you don't need to have array of pointers you can simply have an array too. That will not demand an explicit allocation as in the present case. `char *Psedo[10];` will be `char Psedo[10][MAXLEN]`;

Secondly `strcpy(matrixs.Psedo[i][x], '0')` would be `strcpy(matrixs.Psedo[i], "0")`. Feeding `strcpy` what it wants ... it expects to pointers. In your earlier case the integral value of `char` is considered to be as pointer. That's why the warning. This will also lead to undefined behavior.